# Are there stats for a generic fish creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, animals

I've been looking everywhere for stats for generic fish stats. Fish like trout, bass, carps, and ones of the like.

I don't know if there are any already out there, and I can't seem to find any in the *Monster Manual*. I only have the 3 core rulebooks, so I'm not sure if there are other stats out there in the many campaign books out there.

**Are there monster/creature stats for a generic fish creature in 5e?**

I'm looking for a statblock, not just to use for regular fishing.

Comment: Related: [When skipping over fishing, how much experience should be gained?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110687/38502)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The most generic fish monster is the CR 0 [Quipper](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/quipper) (MM 335) which is also referenced in [Find Familiar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar), there is no more generic fish monster than this option.

> A quipper is a carnivorous fish with sharp teeth. Quippers can adapt
>   to any aquatic environment, including cold subterranean lakes. They
>   frequently gather in swarms; the statistics for a swarm of quippers
>   appear later in this appendix.

[Find Familiar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) (PHB 240):

> You gain the service of a familiar, a [..] fish (quipper)

You can find the [Swarm of Quippers](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/swarm-of-quippers) in the MM on page 338 (for swarms in general for example of generic critters like rats, insects, spider etc see also The Nature of Swarms MM 337)

As the DM, you may call a fish by any name, if you want to point out that the fish are any specific fish like bass, trout or carp and if needed use the statistics of another fish (read Modifying Creatures, MM 6).

For less generic fish monster options (only beasts, snakes excluded), see the CR 0 [Octopus](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/octopus) (BR 146), the CR 0 [Sea Horse](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/sea-horse) (BR 152), the CR  1/8 [Dolphin](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/dolphin) (VGM 208), the CR 1/2 [Giant Sea Horse](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/giant-sea-horse) (MM 328), the CR 1/2 [Reef Shark](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/reef-shark) (MM 336), the CR 1 [Giant Octopus](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/giant-octopus) (MM 326), the CR 2 [Plesiosaurus](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/plesiosaurus) (MM 80), the CR 2 [Hunter Shark](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/hunter-shark) (MM 330), the CR 3 [Killer Whale](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/killer-whale) (MM 331), the CR 5 [Giant Shark](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/giant-shark) (MM 328).

Comment: Pretty sure that the only fish in that list in the final paragraph are the sea horses and sharks. Dolphins, whales, octopi, and plesiosaurs aren't fish, they're mammals, molluscs, and reptiles, respectively.

Comment: @nick012000 in D&D classification mushroom people are plants. Dolphin is closer to fish than mushrooms are to plants, so including them in the answer makes perfect sense.

Comment: Now I need a [carp](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/40d:Carp)

Comment: @MooingDuck Use the Reef Shark stats, I think.

Comment: @nick012000 for that specific encounter the Hunter Shark might be more appropriate ;)